# How can I create a directory in my source control using TFS 2010 SDK?

Tags: tfs, sdk

I want to customize the creation of a TFS project using TFS 2010 SDK.
I have already create a process template and use [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/26/extend-team-projects-and-team-explorer-in-tfs-2010.aspx), but I want to create a specific directory tree for the new team project base on a XML file which describe the tree. My problem is this message; The array must contain at least one element.

```
Parameter name: checkinParameters.PendingChanges
```

I initialize the TFS, map the server folder with a local folder and create directories in both.

```
fooString = Array.Find<WorkingFolder>(workspace.Folders, m => m.ServerItem.Contains("$/FR_DEV"));     

Directory.CreateDirectory(ElementPath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(fooString.ServerItem + ElementTfsPath);
```

After that:

```
PendingChange[] PendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
// Checkin the items we added
int changesetForAdd = workspace.CheckIn(PendingChanges, "Project creation.");
```

However, I get an error for the pending change! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i need to add the directory in the workspace not with a simple path

```
workspace.PendAdd(currentSubDirectory, true);
```

Comment: For more detail from NgM on that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526373/workspace-penadd-exact-syntax/6526805#6526805